# Apache CXF wsdl does not include any data type definition

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl, cxf

I am using Apache CXF 2.4.2 for implementing a SOAP webservice. I followed/adapted the tutorial (see next link) to create a webservice by a contract.

> http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Apache+CXF+Tutorial+-+Building+JAX-WS,+JAXB+and+JPA-based+web+service+with+Apache+CXF,+Spring+and+Hyperjaxb3

In this example, you can see a wsdl and a xsd file which contains the data model. This datamodel is imported by the wsdl file. After that I generate the code with the Maven  cxf-codegen-plugin (v. 2.4.2). Everything seem OK. I can compile my project and also I can consume the webservice on my local maschine by using the Eclipse Webservices Explorer.

But on another computer there I can see only the webservice opererations. The wsdl contains no datamodel (http://*********:18080/webservice/Test?wsdl) and another consumer is not able to generate a client.

I tested another case where I put the data type declarations directly into the wsdl but the effect is the same :-(. It seems so that Apache CXF creates internally a new wsdl on the fly.

> write a wsdl -> generate code -> apache cxf generates wsdl on the fly

Are there any switches where I can change this behavior?

Thanks

~Chris

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. Create a folder META-INF/wsdl within your 'main/resources' an put your wsdl file and xsd files in it.
2. Set the `extraarg` -wsdlLocation option of the cxf-codegen-plugin like this (see http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html and http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html):

   ```
   <wsdlOptions>
     <wsdlOption>
       ...
       <extraargs>
         ...
         <extraarg>-wsdlLocation </extraarg>
         <extraarg>wsdl/yourfile.wsdl</extraarg>
         ...
       <extraargs>
     <wsdlOption>
       ...
   <wsdlOptions>
   ```
3. Make sure, your wsdl and xsd are bundled within your jar. Should be done by default.

CXF should expose your file and not its generated one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problems in publishing the original WSDL.

You can try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955655/use-original-wsdl-to-generate-wsdl-in-cxf/6972459#6972459) and let me know