# CXF: Attaching xsd schemes to make WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, cxf

I'm developing a web-service in some kind of contract-first terms - firstly, I create xsd schemes, secondly, generate classes with JAXB upon them, and then, I want to attach these schemes to WSDL. Here is my applicationContext,xml:

```xml
<jaxws:endpoint id="webService" 
                implementor="#wsImplementer" 
                address="/service">

   <jaxws:schemaLocations>
       <jaxws:schemaLocation>classpath:/xsd/RequestWrapper.xsd</jaxws:schemaLocation>
    </jaxws:schemaLocations>

</jaxws:endpoint>
```

The problem is: the RequestWrapper.xsd contains `<xs:include schemaLocation="ComplexTypes.xsd"/>` and the 
ComplexTypes.xsd contains `<xs:include schemaLocation="SimpleTypes.xsd"/>`. So, when CXF generates the WSDL, it contains the RequestWrapper.xsd scheme with such an include `http://service/path?xsd=ComplexTypes.xsd` which is ok, but if you walk to this link you'll see ComplexTypes.xsd with `<xs:include schemaLocation="SimpleTypes.xsd"/>`. Of course, this is not a valid WSDL cause it cannot load the SimpleTypes.xsd.

I've managed to find the workaround:

1) create a new scheme which consists of includes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       targetNamespace="http://custom/data"
       xmlns="http://custom/data">

<xs:include schemaLocation="SimpleTypes.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="ComplexTypes.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="RequestWrapper.xsd"/>
```

2) delete all the includes from the other schemes.

3)

```xml
<jaxws:schemaLocations>
       <jaxws:schemaLocation>classpath:/xsd/comprise.xsd</jaxws:schemaLocation>
</jaxws:schemaLocations>
```

That worked for me, but, as you can see, all the schemes are not valid (there is no includes). That looks really dull to comment includes all the time before exposing a web service. Can anybody please help me? How to go through this?

So that, I need some kind of scheme location resolver...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder why you specify xsd schemas in applicationContext.xml? May be i don't fully understand your question but when i developed web services using JAXB simply included

```xml
<wsdl:definitions name="myWebService" ...>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:include namespace="your namespace comes here" schemaLocation="RequestWrapper.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
...other part of wsdl
```

So request wrapper includes other xsd files and you can make "includes" inside RequestWrapper.xsd as much as you need.

p.s. in xsd file import like this

```xml
<import namespace="here your namespace" schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, Didar Burmaganov, for immediate answer. The problem is CXF makes WSDL itself. So to make it use my xsds I need to give them to it.

Comment: Dmitry have tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955655/use-original-wsdl-to-generate-wsdl-in-cxf/6972459#6972459
may be it will help you! So you take generated wsdl and add include and tell to CXF to take from your WSDL. This workaround is not good if you often make changes to WSDL file because you'll need to generate again and add "include". There should be more automated version of this.

Comment: Yes, I've thought about developing a wsdl myself. That's hard, but it seems there is no other way: my workaround or wsdl by hand =) I hope somebody will post another variant =)

Comment: Developing from scratch a WSDL file can cause problems (no error check). I thought like this scenario: 
1. generate WSDL using apache (throw away xsd garbage to replace it with own xsd file)
2. insert "include xsd"
So when you change your web service class (annotated with @WebService) you repeat above steps :) Hope it helps.

Comment: Didar Burmaganov, thank you very much. Btw, eclipse has a plugin to crearte WSDLs =).